# pack multiple variables of different datatypes in list/array python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have multiple variables that I need to pack as one and hold it sequentially like in a array or list. This needs to be done in Python and I am still at Python infancy.

E.g. in Python:

```
a = Tom
b = 100
c = 3.14
d = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
```

All the above in one sequential data structure. I can probably try and also a similar implementation I would have done in C++ just for the sake of clarity.

```
struct
{ 
string a;
int b;
float c;
map <char,int> d;// just as an example for dictionary in python
} node;

vector <node> v; // looking for something like this which can be iterable
```

If some one can give me a similar implementation for storing, iterating and modifying the contents would be really helpful. Any pointers in the right direction is also good with me.

Thanks

Comment: This is what you use objects for.

Comment: Read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  You can use a tuple for this, or an object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is what `collections.namedtuple` is for. :) It is just a lighter version of what you suggest (has the same effect as defining a class, but is much shorter to write). :)

Comment: _namedtuple_ has one shortcoming - it is immutable, so if you plan on changing values after you create your structure, better use list or create a regular class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a **dictionary** like Michael proposes (but then you need to access the contents of `v` with `v['a']`, which is a little cumbersome), or you can use the **equivalent of C++'s struct**: a **named tuple**:

```
import collections

node = collections.namedtuple('node', 'a b c d')

# Tom = ...

v = node(Tom, 100, 3.14, {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3})
print node  # node(a=…, b=100, c=3.14, d={'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3})
print node.c  # 3.14
print node[2]  # 3.14 (works too, but is less meaningful and robust than something like node.last_name)
```

This is similar to, but simpler than defining your own class: `type(v) == node`, etc.  Note however, as volcano pointed out, that the values stored in a `namedtuple` cannot be changed (a `namedtuple` is immutable).

If you indeed need to modify the values inside your records, the best option is a **class**:

```
class node(object):
    def __init__(self, *arg_list):
        for (name, arg) in zip('a b c d'.split(), arg_list):
            setattr(self, name, arg)

v = node(1, 20, 300, "Eric")
print v.d  # "Eric"
v.d = "Ajay"  # Works
```

The last option, *which I do not recommend*, is indeed to use **a list or a tuple**, like ATOzTOA mentions: elements must be accessed in a not-so-legible way: `node[3]` is less meaningful than `node.last_name`; also, you cannot easily change the order of the fields, when using a list or a tuple (whereas the order is immaterial if you access a named tuple or custom class attributes).

---

Multiple `node` objects are customarily put in a list, the standard Python structure for such a purpose:

```
all_nodes = [node(…), node(…),…]
```

or

```
all_nodes = []
for … in …:
    all_nodes.append(node(…))
```

or

```
all_nodes = [node(…) for … in …]
```

etc. The best method depends on how the various `node` objects are created, but in many cases a list is likely to be the best structure.

Note, however, that if you need to store something akin to an spreadsheet table and need speed and facilities for accessing its columns, you might be better off with NumPy's [record arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), or a package like [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: +1 @EOL: Thanks. Could you also just tell me once I pack the data in the node, how do I sequentially store it? Is list/array a good option?

Comment: Yes, a list of `node` objects is perfect. Note that usually, Python code does not use arrays: arrays have only one type of objects, and they have a size that cannot be changed, whereas lists are much more expressive: they can contain different kinds of objects, and are meant to be expanded on the fly (with `my_list.append(…)`, in Python).

Comment: Thanks again. I am on python 2.4.3 is that a problem for this approach? Because from collections import namedtuple throws import error

Comment: Yes, Python 2.4 does not have namedtuples. If you cannot install Python 2.6+, you should use a class, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all the values in a dictionary, and have a list of these dictionaries.

`{'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c, 'd': d}`

Otherwise, if this data is something that could be represented by a class, for example a 'Person'; create a class of type Person and create an object of that class with your data:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use lists:

```
a = "Tom"
b = 100
c = 3.14
d = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}

data = [a, b, c, d]

print data
for item in data:
    print item
```

Output:

```
['Tom', 100, 3.14, {'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}]
Tom
100
3.14
{'y': 2, 'x': 1, 'z': 3}
```

Comment: While a list is fine, a tuple might be more appropriate: they are typically used when each position in the tuple represents some defined quantity (e.g., the abscissa of a point, etc.), like in the question. However, whether this is relevant here depends on whether the original poster wants to be able to modify the records or not…

Comment: After thinking of it, I would not recommend a list or a tuple, finally: data[3] is less meaningful than data.last_name. Also, changing the order of the fields at a later time becomes difficult. Using lists and tuples for structured records thus yields code which is harder to write and maintain.

Comment: @EOL any recommendations on what structure is best for maintaining structured records

Comment: The best I can think of is in my full answer (named tuple or custom class).